# Symfony2: functional test of record edit fails

Tags: symfony, phpunit, functional-testing

I'm on the steep part of the learning curve for functional tests.  On a simple form that changes an agency's status (Yes->No, No->Yes), the record edit fails.  The test code is:

```
$crawler = $client->request('GET', '/agency/manage');
//read agency table
$nodeValues = $crawler->filter('td')->each(function ($node, $i) {
    return $node->nodeValue;
});

//$initial = number of Active=Yes agencies
$initial = 0;
foreach ($nodeValues as $node) {
    if ($node == 'Yes') {
        $initial ++;
    }
}
//edit agency to Active=No
$crawler = $client->request('GET', '/agency/1/edit');
$form = $crawler->selectButton('Edit')->form();
$form['agency[active]'] = 'No';
$crawler = $client->submit($form);

$crawler = $client->request('GET', '/agency/manage');

$nodeValues = $crawler->filter('td')->each(function ($node, $i) {
    return $node->nodeValue;
});

//$final = number of Active=Yes agencies
$final = 0;
foreach ($nodeValues as $node) {
    if ($node == 'Yes') {
        $final ++;
    }
}

$this->assertTrue($initial > $final);
```

For my test case, both initial and final values are 2.  I've built a test that properly adds an agency so I know I'm not totally off track.  (I also imagine there are easier ways to count the number of times Yes appears in a table.)

Thanks.

Comment: What does `$client->getResponse()->getContent()` look like after `$crawler = $client->submit($form);` You should check that the response is successful after each POST/GET with `$this->assertTrue($client->getResponse()->isSuccessful());` to make sure that your testing configuration doesn't have any issues, or another exception isn't being thrown during a request.

Comment: @james_t: `$client->getResponse()->getContent()` appears to be empty in Windows shell (only .).  `$this->assertTrue($client->getResponse()->isSuccessful())` assertion does not fail.

Comment: Correction: `...getContent()` returns html of expected page when `var_dump()` is used.

Comment: But wrong: After adding code to write content to a file so I could see the whole thing, content is the edit page, not the page that should be returned after a successful edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer: fix the routing of the edit action!  Test now is passed.